# How to calculate x/y in a different coordinate system in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to calculate Northing Easting in QGIS.  I can get it to calculate my lat/long using $y and $x in the field calculator.  I changed coordinate systems to what I want it displayed at, but it's still calcing the lat/long

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `Set CRS for Layer` if you want to reproject your data. It changes only the CRS definition, but does not recalculate any coordinate.

So set it back to what it was before (WGS84 I assume), and use `Save As ...` under a different name and different CRS.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving a copy of the layer and when you get to the 'save as' menu, set the CRS there instead. I had similar issues and that worked for me, although it may be a bit of workaround more than a solution.